# Comma separator for \citet and semicolon separator for \citep (in the last reference with \citet)

Tags: natbib, punctuation

I need an answer about this problem and many of the accepted solution herein (StackExchange) do not work for me!

For example

1. [A comma separator for \citet and a semicolon separator for \citep simultaneously?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3125/a-comma-separator-for-citet-and-a-semicolon-separator-for-citep-simultaneously/192068#192068)
2. [natbib, hyperref and citation inside a float figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71501/natbib-hyperref-and-citation-inside-a-float-figure)

The `\citet` command doesn't changes to add commas when there are multiple references and LaTeX keeps adding semicolons..

If I have `\citet{Mark:2001a,John:2003a,Bob:2011b,Chris:2012a}` -> I would like to get

Bob (2011), Chris (2012), Mark (2001) and John (2003)

**Note, how LaTeX could add an and in the last reference as above - automatically?!**

while if I have `\citep{Mark:2001a,John:2003a,Bob:2011b,Chris:2012a}` -> I would like to get

(Bob, 2011; Chris, 2012; Mark, 2001; John, 2003)

Thanks a ton for your answers!

Comment: You've told us what you do *not* want. Could you be a bit more specific as to what you do need?

Comment: I hope now I am much clear and I look forward to your or the communities help!

Comment: The `natbib` user guide states, on page 9, that "[m]ultiple citations in `\citet` are also not recommended (nor are they in my opinion meaningful)". Put differently, multiple citations are really only recommended for `\citep`. Incidentally, is there something stopping you from writing `\citet{Mark:2001a}, \citet{John:2003a}, \citet{Bob:2011b} and \citet{Chris:2012a}`? (Note that some -- but certainly not all -- authors would also want to insert a comma before the `and` conjunction. For `\citep`, have you tried `\setcitestyle{citesep={;}}`?

Answer (score 10):

Use `\citet{Mark:2001a}, \citet{John:2003a}, \citet{Bob:2011b}, and \citet{Chris:2012a}`

See for your `\citep{}` issue the Reference sheet for natbib usage from CTAN.
http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natnotes.pdf

=> Use the command `\setcitestyle` with a list of comma-separated keywords (without spaces) as argument ... . Between citations: `semicolon` or `comma` or `citesep={char}`

In your case: `\setcitestyle{citesep={;}}`